# How to set space separator to float DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, android, decimal

How to set space as thousand separator for DecimalFormat in float? I want to show 13,52 as 13,5, but 13,00 as 13 and I did this with

```
new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(fIncome)
```

but I want to 1400,5 be 1 400,5 and 1400 to be 1 400.

For double I use this code (I don't want to shows numbers after comma in dCount):

```
String.format("%,d", (int)dCount)
```

But how to use this for floating number with 1 number after comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got what I want :)

```
new DecimalFormat("###,###.#").format(fIncome)
```

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer probably lacks a few lines of code, because it doesn't work as described. Here's how I did it:

```
private static final String DECIMAL_FORMAT = "###,###.#";

private String formatValue(Number value, String formatString) {
        DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
        formatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        formatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(formatString, formatSymbols);
        return formatter.format(value);
    }
```

I then call it like this:

```
formatValue(value, DECIMAL_FORMAT);
```

To explain how it works, the `.` in DECIMAL_FORMAT is replaced with decimalSeparator and the `,` is replaced with groupingSeparator, which is a space in this case.