# How to format double with DecimalFormatSymbols and currency?

Tags: android, formatting, double, decimal, currency

My result should look like this: $100 00,99
I managed to format the number as I need, but without the currency.
I managed to get the currency separately, but can't get the two together.
For the numbering format, I used `DecimalFormatSymbol` as in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432122/how-to-set-space-separator-to-float-decimalformat).

```
 private fun formatValue(value: Double, formatString: String): String {
     val formatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH)
     formatSymbols.decimalSeparator = ','
     formatSymbols.groupingSeparator = ' '
     val formatter = DecimalFormat(formatString, formatSymbols)
     return formatter.format(value)
 }

 formatValue(amount ,"###,###.00")
```

For the currency I used this code:

```
fun getFormattedCurrency(currency: String, amount: Double): String {
     val c = Currency.getInstance(currency)
     val nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
     nf.currency = c
     return  nf.format(amount)
}
```

How can I combine the two?

Comment: Would'nt it be simpler if you just added currency symbol at the end? If you are showing the amount in some TextView, just do something like `myTextView.text = currency + amount.toString()`

Comment: also don't forget that currency is formatted by Locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```
    val decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols().apply {
        decimalSeparator = ','
        groupingSeparator = ' '
        setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("AED"))
    }


    val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("$ #,###.00", decimalFormatSymbols)
    val text = decimalFormat.format(2333222)
    println(text) //$ 2 333 222,00


    val decimalFormat2 = DecimalFormat("¤ #,###.00", decimalFormatSymbols)
    val text2 = decimalFormat2.format(2333222)
    println(text2) //AED 2 333 222.00
```

Notifiy that if you use ¤ instead of specific currency symbol like $,€ it will use a symbol according to currency instance you create. Also you can get more info from docs. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Also you can find ISO 4217 codes in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Comment: Thanks! Almost there... text2 doesn't  have a comma as a separator, although text does. saw this in the doc: `currency sign; replaced by currency symbol; if doubled, replaced by international currency symbol; if present in a pattern, the monetary decimal separator is used instead of the decimal separator.` Anyway to bypass it?

Comment: Happy to hear it helps :)